# Invalid XML Error When Downloading From Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-io, xml-parsing, download

I am trying to write a servlet that will download a `.pptx` file from a known path on the server.  After calling the servlet the AJAX method calling it returns an error.  The text status is `parseerror` and the error thrown is `Error {stack: (...), message: "Invalid XML: PK���D[Conten…edia/slide10_image_rId2.pngPK))�U�"}`  To my knowledge the XML is indeed valid as I have tried various powerpoint files created both programatically and through Microsoft Powerpoint itself.

The relevant code:

```
            response.reset();
            response.resetBuffer();
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"presentation.pptx\"");
            File file=new File(root+sessionID+"/myPresentation.pptx");
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            response.flushBuffer();
```

I have tried changing the content type to `application/octet-stream` and using other `.pptx` as well as various other methods of streaming the data without the use of `IOUtils` and all of which end with the same error.  Other things I have determined: the InvalidXML error is always in the last `.xml` part.  Also, regardless of the presence of the `response.setContentLength((int) file.length());` the program writes the same number of

Am I missing anything or is anything wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You cannot fire a file download request through ajax. Remove the ajax call and it will work.

Comment: The `PK` indicates that you are receiving a zip file, not XML.  The content type header is advisory for the client. You have to make sure you actually send what you are advertising.  In this case, the file `..../myPresentation.pptx` is probably compressed.  If you open it in a text editor on the system where it resides, what do you see?

Comment: @JimGarrison When opening it in notepad I see a variety of symbols such as "$¨³ÀHt,,u)E{íìoµŸ³_Ò3”d;Ùu³A—D¦†Ã3gÎC¿ÛæÂØpYge14"

Comment: Then the file is not XML.  Are the first 2 bytes `PK`?  If so it is a zip-compressed archive.

Comment: @JimGarrison `docx`, `xlsx` and `pptx` suffixes can be replaced by `zip` and you can see the real content of these new office formats :). Inside of them, there are XML files.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, the first 2 bytes are PK.  I changed the MIME type to the standard for .zip files `application/octet-stream` and the error no longer occurs.  However now the client is not prompted to "save as" for the file.  Am I now experiencing the fact that as Luiggi Mendoza said "You cannot fire a file download request through ajax"?